# Load appSettings based on Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In the same way you can load appsettings.Development.json by setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development, is there a way to load a specific json file based on the Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Could I somehow use Beanstalk tags, for example:
elasticbeanstalk:environment-name = dev-site
elasticbeanstalk:environment-name = prod-site

To load:
appsettings.dev-site.json
and
appsettings.prod-site.json

If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating .ebextensions/command.config with this code. Then I just change the environment value before I deploy. There appears to be a way to add environment variables in the elastic beanstalk instance, however it doesn't seem to work. This solution seems to work.

```
commands:
  01_create_env_variable:
    command: "powershell.exe [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT', 'Development', 'Machine')"
```